# Regex, test to see if characters other than exists

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to use regex to see if any character other than a certain set exists.

For example, I'd like to test for the letters 'p', 'v', 'c' in a string.  If any other characters are in the string, I want the test to return True.  If only 'p', 'v', 'c' or a combination thereof exists, I want the test to return False.

'v' returns False

'pv' returns False

'pvc' returns False

'pd' returns True

'p(' returns True

'apvc' returns True

'xyz' returns True

How would I express this using re?
Thanks.

Comment: You do realise that `regex` is definitely the wrong tool for this, right?

Comment: Also - does at least one of `pvc` have to be present? eg: what would `xyz` return?

Comment: @JonClements What would be the tool/code for this?  xyz should return True

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set(..)`

```
if set(yourString) - set("pvc"):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Edit: this should be turned into a single expression.

```
return set(your_string) - set('pvc')
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution

Comment: You could also write this as `set(your_string).difference('pvc')`

Answer (score 3):

I think this most straightforwardly captures your intent:

```
any(char not in 'pvc' for char in mystring)
```

It should be clear to anyone reading the code what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
not (re.search('^[pvc]+$', string))
```

Not sure what you want if string is empty, and this one will return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

x = 'pvc'

regex = re.compile(r'[^p|v|c]')

if regex.search(x) is not None:

    print True

else:

    print False
```